# return only one row for complex multi join sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

--I have the following sql. I only want the first row from the account but am receiving roughly 39 rows of each account.  I have tried top 1,  as shown below.  I don't quite understand where to add the "distinct top 1" or where to add the Row_number =1 so as not to get duplicates --Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is your RDBMS (SQL *flavor*)?

Comment: Why are you “unable to do so”? Do you get an error? What is it? You don't get the results you expect? What results do you get? What results do you expect?

Comment: Microsoft sql server mgt studio

Comment: have you tried `SELECT TOP 1`?

Comment: I've tried select top 1.  I still get many repeated accounts.  where should I put it?  I tried here:-select
  (select top 1 fa.name) as AccountName,
  (select top 1 fa.accountnumber)  as AccountNumber,
  (select top 1 fp.name) as ProductName,
  fp.productnumber as ProductNumber,
  fsr.snap_name as ABLRegion,
  fa.snap_localchamberidname as AccountLocalChamber,

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM( --Your query here)`

Comment: I only get one row if i add this at the start of my query

Comment: Can you provide the table data or the data you got in the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sample code would be

```
Select (select top 1 fieldname from table1 where id=mastertable.id order by fieldnamesort) result from mastertable.
```

If mastertable is unique otherwise put distinct.

Alternatively you can use max for top 1 depending on the requirement.