# How do I create a select and then only provide details on this data SQL

Tags: sql

I have read the feedback and now understand joins a lot better but I am still having trouble with duplicate tuples in my results.  Specifically, from the following sql I am receiving duplicate invoice lines.  Example of result:-

```
accountnumber   Invoice UnitPrice   Units   GSTIncAmt
10025   MEM010206406    700          1      700
10025   MEM010206406    2475         1      2475
10025   MEM010206406    700          1      700
10025   MEM010206406    2475         1      2475
```

I need to pick up all active products sold(from the SNAP_activeproduct).  then pick up any invoices that don't have a product (from the filteredinvoice table.

When I run the following sql I get all the information required BUT the Invoice line (i.e. two products can be on the one invoice) are duplicated.  any help appreciated

```
<select distinct
--(select fa.accountnumber where fa.statecodename = 'Active' and ape.statecode = 1) as Accountnumber,
fa.accountnumber
--,fa.name
--,ape.SNAP_Status as 'ProdStatus_tobeadded'    
--,fid.snap_pricelistidname
--,fp.productnumber
--,ape.snap_productidName as 'ProductName'
--,fp.producttypecode
--,fp.producttypecodename
--,convert (varchar,ape.CreatedOn,103) as InvoiceDate
,ape.snap_invoiceidName as Invoice
--, ape.SNAP_ProductType as 'ProdTypetobeadded'
--,fi.name as InvoiceNumber
,ape.snap_productidName
,str(fid.priceperunit) as UnitPrice 
,str(fid.quantity) as Units
,str(fid.priceperunit*fid.quantity) As GSTIncAmt
,str(fid.snap_otherdiscamount) as 'Discount'
,str(fid.snap_amountafterdiscount) as 'Amt After Discount'
,fi.statecodename as 'Invoice Status'
,fid.baseamount as BaseAmt
,fid.extendedamount
,fid.snap_amountafterdiscount
,SUBSTRING(fid.snap_financedata,4,charindex(':',fid.snap_financedata))   AS Entity
,fid.snap_dbcode as 'Entity Name'
,SUBSTRING(fid.snap_financedata,8,charindex(':',fid.snap_financedata))   AS ReportingUnit
,COALESCE(convert(varchar,fi.snap_paiddate,103),'') as 'Paid Date'
,fi.snap_salespersonidname as Salesperson
,fa.snap_accountmanageridname as AccountManager
,fa.snap_noofemployeesname as NoEmployee
,fa.snap_anzsicdivisionname as DivisionIndustry
,fa.snap_anzsicsubdivisionname  as SubDivisionIndustry
,fa.snap_regionidname as Region
FROM SNAP_activeproduct ape
left join FilteredProduct fp
on ape.snap_productid = fp.productid

left join FilteredAccount fa
on fa.accountid = ape.snap_accountid    

left join FilteredInvoice fi    
on ape.snap_invoiceid = fi.invoiceid    

left join FilteredInvoiceDetail fid
on fi.invoiceid = fid.invoiceid
and fi.invoiceid = ape.snap_invoiceid   

where ape.snap_status in  (1,2,3,5)
--and fa.accountnumber = '10025'
order by fa.accountnumber >
```

Comment: Please provide sample data. What is your definition of a duplicate? Don't fiddle about with temp tables. You should understand your joins properly and understand why 'duplicates' are appearing. If you think products are causing 'duplicates'. then your join to products is probably incorrect. Is column `snap_account_id` unique in table `SNAP_activeproduct`? note I am **assuming** this is your product table... your description is very unclear.

Comment: Perhaps you should complete this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983774/return-only-one-row-for-complex-multi-join-sql If you're not going to finish that one we can assume you won't finish this one either.

Comment: I have tried to complete the other one but can't see HOW to select "correct answer" .  where do i select "answered"?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I suggest you add some detail to your question here (as suggested in my comment) then also add the type of database your are using - sql server? Oracle? FYI you can do what you want to do (does it in two steps), but you **still** need to explain how the data fits together. Once you explain/understand correct joins you can get your query right without messing about with multiple steps

Comment: So... when you say duplicate what is duplicate? Are product names repeating unexpectedly? They key is to identify whether `snap_accountid` is unique, and this is one way to do it: `select count(*) RC, count(distinct snap_accountid) KC from SNAP_activeproduct`. If you get the same number, this column is unique. If RC > KC then it is not unique and you shouldn't be joining on it.

Comment: thanks Nick.  I read up on SQL joins so a bit clearer.  the duplicate is on the invoice line level.

Comment: accountnumber Invoice UnitPrice Units GSTIncAmt
10025 MEM010206406 700         1                   700
10025 MEM010206406 2475 1                 2475
10025 MEM010206406 700         1                   700
10025 MEM010206406 2475 1                  2475

Comment: I assume by "Invoice Line" you mean table `FilteredInvoiceDetail` - please be specific. The simple answer is don't join to that table. However you are selecting columns from that table such as `fid.baseamount`. What are you doing with those? They don't appear in your sample recordset.

Comment: If you don't need those columns but you need to ensure a matching record exists, use the `EXISTS` record. If you do need those columns then you need to pre-aggregate `FilteredInvoiceDetail` up to the level you need _before_ you join to the table.

Comment: So if you can confirm you mean table `FilteredInvoiceDetail `, and tell me if you really need to see columns from that table I can help further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see any data or any explanation but I will assume that you have a classic header/line model where a single header has multiple lines.

For example there is **one** header record with `header_id = 134`. header id is unique in the header table.

### Header Table

```
Header_ID    TotalAmount     TotalTax   Customer_ID
134          $500            $50        774
```

There are three lines joined to this header. So you have three records in the line table also with `header_id=134`, but they also have a line id. This table is unique on header_id + line_id

### Line Table

```
Header_ID    Line_ID    SalePrice   Qty   LineAmount
134          1          $125        2     $250
134          2          $10         10    $100
134          3          $150        1     $150
```

Now when we join these tables...

```
SELECT H.Header_ID, H.Customer_ID, H.TotalAmount, L.Line_ID, L.LineAmount
FROM 
HeaderTable As H
INNER JOIN
LineTable As L
ON H.Header_ID = L.Header_ID
WHERE Header_ID = 134
```

We get data like this:

```
Header_ID    TotalAmount Customer_ID   Line_ID    LineAmount
134          $500        774           1          $250
134          $500        774           2          $100
134          $500        774           3          $150
```

It looks like `TotalAmount` is a duplicate.... but it isn't it's just doing exactly what you're asking - giving you one recordset which combines duplicate tables.

I hope this helps you understand your issue but more importantly lets you understand the level of detail you need to provide when asking a question.

Comment: Hi Nick.    did add a lot more data above?  anyway let me try to add it here.  firstly can you see this?  ta

Comment: Yeah I see that now. I've added a comment above.

Comment: I cant see any additional commentary.

Comment: found the issue!!!   Its in the join between the invoice and the invoice line.  thanks for help guys

Answer (score -1):

Be more specific in your SQL Joins. Depending on your product table and how you join everything up, you could use a Left Join or Right Join.

[image]

Comment: What this colourful diagram fails to mention, and is in fact key to this question, is the _number_ of rows returned. Joins don't just intersect. They can return multiple rows. Two rows in one table matching two rows in another table = 4 rows.